# PBS Kids Point-and-click Adventure Game

Tags: story-identification, video-games, educational

At the school I went to in the early 2010s the first-second graders used to play some educational (the kind that's not really explicitly educational as in it teaches kids but the kind that teachers approve of having technology class make them play) isometric point-and-click adventure game.

I remember there was a level with a minigame about bats in a place called "Spookane" (get it?) and a villain who I think looked like a donut. It was on PBS Kids, I'm pretty sure, and had a cartoony art style. The movement was by clicking on a grid on top of a background of a road. It was more the kind of point-and-click game where you move around and see things than the kind where you click on trash cans that do weird things like Putt-Putt.

There were about five chapters, and the last one needed you to make an account with a username and password.

I'm almost definitely sure it was connected to no specific TV show, but I didn't watch PBS Kids so it might have.

I looked at games tagged "adventure" on PBS Kids and didn't find it, so it maybe has been taken down.

Comment: [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100208054235/http://pbskids.org:80/games/)'s the PBS website from early 2010. Do you remember how you found the game on the webpage? Or maybe do you have a more precise year?

Comment: I'm a bit torn, the villain looking like a donut certainly is unusual, but were there others, more concrete sci-fi/fantasy elements?

Comment: @DEADPOOL I’m severely confused...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[*Cyberchase: Mission Motherboard*](https://web.archive.org/web/20180830123217if_/http://pbskids.org:80/cyberchase/games/quest-1-mission-motherboard). It is based on [Cyberchase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyberchase), a PBS Kids cartoon.

From what I played of it to check if it matched your description, it seems to not have a villain who looks like a donut but it does have a character who likes donuts.

[image: A fake advertisement: "Eat at Buzz's donut shop / Best Donuts in Cybserspace! Located in R-Fair City." There is a picture of a round thing with antennae eating a donut.]

There is no town called "Spookane"; there is a haunted area called Castleblanca. Looking for what this could be confused with, I found that *MySims*, a Wii game from a few years before you played this, [has an area called Spookane](https://mysims.fandom.com/wiki/Spookane). *Earthbound Beginnings* also [has a place also called Spookane](https://earthbound.fandom.com/wiki/Spookane), but that game is very old and only ever sold in Japan until recently.

[image: A fake advertisement: "We're going batty! Help wanted. Eerie Inn, Castleblanca." There is a picture of two bats.]

It is pretty cartoony and has the grid one clicks squares on.

[image: A screenshot of the game, showing what it looks lik]

---

The game was removed from the website after I posted it. However, I changed it to be to the Internet Archive's copy of the page, which seems pretty alright, having working sound and the like.